# mysql results too large - htaccessfile

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query, that should be returning about 16,000 results.

Apparently that is too much for my current settings.

What PHP variable would I increase to allow all results to show?

memory_limit    128M
post_max_size   8M
upload_max_filesize 2M

Something else?

Comment: cant you stagger the fetch?

Comment: even if you can allocate the memory, don't, chunk it and loop it. much kinder resource use age for what ever else the server is also doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration option you should increase is `memory_limit`, but why do you need to handle 16,000 rows in your application at one time? Are you sure this is necessary?

Often times, you can consolidate this logic to a `while` loop that queries the database for batches of a few hundred, or even a thousand rows at a time.